# http proxy error at /api/auth/signup: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete

Tags: reactjs, node.js, dependencies, vite

> [vite] http proxy error at /api/auth/signup:
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)

here is my api fetch code

```
const res=await fetch('/api/auth/signup',{
method: 'POST',
headers:{
'Content-Type':'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify(formData),
});
```

vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy:{
      '/api' :{
        target:'http://localhost:3000',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin : true,
        ws:true,
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [react()],
})
```

here is vite.config.js file

seem to have added everything still stuck here please help

with console.log out put is showing its going on localhost:5173 but my backend server is at localhost:3000
SignIn.jsx:18

> console.log
> POST http://localhost:5173/api/auth/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)

i have tried adding different thing suggested on other questions but didn't seem to work
and on

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code, and everything worked fine for me
you can check your code and edit accordingly, it might work for you too.

THIS IS MY PROXY SETUP IN THE vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{ 
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
        secure: false,
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

Note the changes on the localhost in the 'target' value
-Here is my post-request for the same:

```
  // submit to the backend
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/api/auth/signup', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            })
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```